# fill @Html.HiddenFor in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i have a @Html.HiddenFor . i wanna fill it by my td (1234569876) .

how can do it?

```
           <tr>
                <td valign="top"><strong>Code:</strong></td>
                <td colspan="2" align="right" id="tdPobox">1234569876</td>

            </tr> 


      //i don't know how should i write it
          @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PostalCode )
```

Answer (score 2):

The Id of this hidden input should be "PostalCode"

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PostalCode )
```

So by adding some Jquery script, you can  dynamicaly get some values from any part of your web page like this :

```
$(function () {
    // Set the Value of input with the content of td
    $("#PostalCode").val($("#tdPobox").html());
}
```

Join this part of JavaScript after the implementation of JQuery (generaly the Section Scripts is fine for that) and it should work =)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `jquery` then solution is below:

```
$(function(){
    $("#PostalCode ").val($("#tdPobox").html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `properties` of model gets bind with the help of `NAME` in the html control.

Therefore your approcah should be as follows:

```
$(function () {
    $("input[name*='PostalCode']").val($("#tdPobox").html());
}
```